# Polymer: How to insert a new element after an element?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

There is no API for insert new element after an element.
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api

I am looking similar jQuery method `.after()`

```
<paper-input></paper-input>
```

I want to insert new element `paper-menu` after `paper-input`

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with appendChild?

```
    var el = document.createElement('paper-menu'),
        parent = this.querySelector('paper-input').parentNode
    Polymer.dom(parent).appendChild(el)
```

For reference [`.after()`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.after):

```
function () {
    return this.domManip(arguments, function (elem) {
        if (this.parentNode) {
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, this.nextSibling);
        }
    });
}
```

So you could also do:

```
var el = document.createElement('paper-menu'),
    before = this.querySelector('paper-input')
Polymer.dom(before.parentNode).insertBefore(el, before.nextSibling)
```

Comment: Just thought to mention that while the above works, Polymer currently does not support imperative insertion of data-bound nodes, ie inserting something like `<paper-menu attr-for-item-title="{{_myItemTitle}}"></paper-menu>` will not work. Ref: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1778